# Plotting Charts for monthly counts per company

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a program that prints out bar charts or CSV files for monthly counts per company. So I should have a graph for January which has all the companies on the x axis and the counts on the y axis

So I am able to split my date in to month and year and I want that to be the heading. So I am able to program my df table to be this:

```
Date Modified Company                      
2019-01       Apple         113         0.0
              Blackberry     66         0.0
              LG             73         0.0
              Linux         115         0.0
              Microsoft     187         0.0
              Panasonic     336         0.0
              Samsung       151         0.0
2019-02       Apple         151         0.0
              Blackberry    163         0.0
              LG            301         0.0
              Linux         108         0.0
              Microsoft     199         0.0
              Panasonic     142         0.0
              Samsung       304         0.0
2019-03       Apple         358         0.0
              Blackberry    230         0.0
              LG            288         0.0
              Linux         464         0.0
              Microsoft      53         0.0
              Panasonic     113         0.0
              Samsung       177         0.0
```

```
df['Date Modified']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('M')
df=df.groupby(["Date Modified","Company"]).sum()
print(df)

df = pd.read_csv("Sample_Data.csv")


df['Date Modified']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('M')
df=df.groupby(["Date Modified","Company"]).sum()
```

So there's currently nothing faulty with this program. I want to create monthly graphs with every company listed on the x axis and the count on the y axis with a title containg the month and year so for e.g 2019-03 or 2019-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
months = df.index.levels[0]

for month in months:
    data = df.loc[month]
    data.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title =str(month), legend=True)
```